# Importing Django Custom User Model From Another App Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have an app called profiles and it has model named Profile

```
from poros.abstracts.models import Model
from django.db import models
from poros.users.models import User


class Profile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile', )
```

the Profile model has a field name `user` which has `OneToOneField` relationship with my Django custom user `User`. The problem now is it returns me an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Don't import; use a string, in the format `appname.ModelName`, in the field definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't refer to the user model directly, it is recommended by django by refer to the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

[Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile', )
```